# ClassNotFoundException on Dropbox

Tags: java, applet, dropbox, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to load a Java applet onto a website, using:

```html
<applet code="snakeApplet.class" archive="SnakeApplet.jar" width=640 height=480>
```

Note: `snakeApplet.class` has lower case 's' and `SnakeApplet.jar` has upper case 'S'

I'm storing both the html file and `SnakeApplet.jar` in the same folder on Dropbox, but when I go to the link containing the html file and load the applet, I get the error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: snakeApplet.class
```

I've also tried `code=snakeApplet.jar`, `archive="./SnakeApplet.jar"` and `archive="share_SnakeApplet.jar_link"` replaced with the actual share link provided by Dropbox.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So to be clear.  The applet is on drop-box.  What is the URL(1)?  The HTML is ..where?  What is the URL(1)?  1) And by 'URL' I do mean a fully qualified URL we can follow, to see them.

Comment: HTML file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmls9oxstjo2u8r/snake.html
              , Jar file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kd4xqv7v258lmti/SnakeApplet.jar
,
Website: http://jerry.pancakeapps.com/snake.html

Comment: I'm using Pancake.io to host my web page. So how it works is, I store both SnakeApplet.jar and snake.html in my dropbox folder home/App/Pancake.io, to see the web page you go to http://jerry.pancakeapps.com/snake.html.

Comment: There is something wrong with the Jar.  My Zip app. (Pea Zip) thinks it is password protected.  Since no Jar is, it seems to be corrupted.  Try ***downloading it back from*** DropBox and run `jar -tvf SnakeApplet.jar`.

Comment: In fact, I *suspect* that DropBox is not inviting us to use it as a binary storage space for Java apps., and all this is a result of that..

Comment: Using Cygwin/cmd.exe: 'jar is not recognized as an internal or external command' :/

Comment: *"'jar is not recognized"*  OK - your Java environment is not set up correctly, but why tell me, and what do you expect me to do about it?  Note that if you have questions on setting up the Java SDK environment, they are entirely unrelated to a 'CNFE in applet'.  On the topic of *this question* it might also help if you identify what package the applet is in.  Paste the lines from the `snakeApplet.java` file from the first line (maybe with package name), including the imports, to the line starting with `public class snakeApplet extends ..` inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<applet codebase="SnakeApplet.jar" code="Packagename(snakeAppletjar).Applet" width="800" height="300">
```

i meant that like if your package name is snakeApplet then put `code=`snakeApplet.applet

Comment: I get the error ClassNotFoundException: Packagename(snakeAppletjar).Applet